# How to include template's value inside link or table in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I search the documentation but I didn't know exactly how to call that.

I have a template `Index2Name` that return a name based on an index.
I'm trying to use that name in a link:

```
[[Articles/{{Index2Name|0001}}|{{Index2Name|0001}}]]
```

or

```
Image:Big-0001.png|link=Articles/{{Index2Name|0001}}|''{{Index2Name|0001}}''
```

In the last example, the name is printed but the link doesn't work. (In gallery element)

It doesn't work. The value from the template is printed but it is not converted to a link.

How can I make this works? And does this have a name? (For future reference)

EDIT: `Index2Name` is a simple switch returning a few words depending of the id. Since I'm using subpages I only want the name to appear (Example: MyArticle) but the link is `Articles/MyArticle`

Comment: What exactly does `{{Index2Name|0001}` expand to?

Comment: If the documentation doesn't help enough, [use the debugger](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:ExpandTemplates) :-)

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Does the first example work?

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify exactly what you want to happen please. (Where you want to link and how you want it to look).

But for example if you use:

```
[[Image:Big-0001.png|''{{Index2Name|0001}}'']]
```

It will link to the page `Image:Big-0001.png` with the link text being the output of:

```
''{{Index2Name|0001}}''
```

Or if you use:

```
[[Image:Big-001.jpg|link=Articles/{{Index2Name|0001}}]]
```

The image, when clicked, will redirect you to the output of:

```
{{Index2Name|0001}}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear :/ the link go to a subpage, but I want the text of that link to only be the name without the parent page name to appear.

Comment: @HypeWolf What exactly do you think `[[Image:Big-001.jpg|link={{Index2Name|0001}}]]` does? It doesn't produce any text, it just means that when the image is clicked you will be take to the value of `link=`. Therefore I cant see what the problem is unless of course `[[Articles/{{Index2Name|0001}}|{{Index2Name|0001}}]]` doesn't work for you either?